# How to install screen on Linux?

Tags: linux, display, python, putty, django

I'm trying to install `screen` on linux without any luck.

I tried `yum install screen` which resulted in:

> CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

I'm not *root* since it's a shared webhost, though there must be a way to host my (django) website without stopping when I exit *Putty*.

Comment: it sounds like you've got several other questions here, but your webhost are probably best positioned to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install screen using `yum install screen` if you don't have root privileges (other access controls exist, but you're very unlikely to have them if it's a shared web host).

However, you don't need screen to run Django permanently. You need a way to *daemonize* the process, that way it won't stop when the terminal is disconnected. A popular option for Django is [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), but there are literally dozens of ways to daemonize a process in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried installing Celery but it doesn't support Python 2.7 (there's no way for me to update python). Any other suggestions?

Comment: The _dozens of ways to daemonize a process_... Please do some research. Btw, according to the pypy documentation, Celery 4.1.0 does support Python 2.7.